# Filter product_set in django-mptt

Tags: django, mptt

Have 2 models

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get tree from both models. 
Now i can get:

in views

```
nodes = Category.objects.all()
```

in template

```
{% for n in nodes %}
  {% for t in n.product_set.all %}
```

But i want to get

```
nodes = Category.objects.all().**insert_to_category_product_with_filter**(id__in=[list_id])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution via template_tag

```
@register.filter()
def filter_GET(node, GET):
    qs = node.product_set.all().prefetch_related('product_set')

    product = GET.get('product', None)
    if product:
        qs = qs.filter(product_id=product)

    any_more = GET.get('any_more', None)

    return qs
```

in template

```
{% for n in node|filter_GET:request.GET %}
```